# How do I assign property values for objects in one array based on key/value pairs in another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

`var fields = [{Name: 'FirstName', Value: '', Display: 'First Name'}, {...}]`

I have another array that looks like this:

`var nameValue = [{'FirstName':'John'}, {'LastName':'Doe'}, ...]`

How do I assign the Value property for each field in the first array using the name/value pairs in the second array?

Desired result:

`fields = [{Name: 'FirstName', Value: 'John', Display: 'First Name'}, {...}]`

Comment: Is the second object in the first array of the same form as the first, with a different name, or is it information about the LastName?

Comment: Presumably, there is an object with a `Name` value that matches each key in the second array.

Comment: What code have you tried? Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. How could anyone help you with only a partial data set (that doesn't even line up) being shown?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an object first with all needed values and iterate `fields`, make a check if a property with the name exists and then assign the value.

```js
var fields = [{ Name: 'FirstName', Value: '', Display: 'First Name' }],
    nameValue = [{ FirstName: 'John' }, { LastName: 'Doe' }],
    values = Object.assign({}, ...nameValue);
   
fields.forEach(o => (o.Name in values) && (o.Value = values[o.Name]));

console.log(fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop, check, assign:

```
fields.forEach(function(field) {
    let key = field.Name;
    for (let i = 0; i < nameValue.length; i++) {
        for (let nameKey in nameValue[i]) {
            if (nameKey == key) {
                field.Value = nameValue[i][key]
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First combine all the names and values into a single object:

```
var nvObject = {};
nameValue.forEach(function (e) {
    for (key in e) {
        nvObject[key] = e[key];
    }
});
```

Now `nvObject = { FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'Doe', ... }`. Perhaps you could construct `nameValue` like this in the first place, instead of making it an array of objects.

Then you can use this to update the other array.

```
$fields.forEach(function (e) {
    if (e.Name in nvObject) {
        e.Value = nvObject[e.Name];
    }
});
```